# Ubuntu Installation Issues Acer Aspire E5-411

Tags: system-installation, acer

I've been having this issue installing ubuntu on my Acer laptop. I've only encountered this error just today and a few days back then, my OS was just running fine. Every time I try installing ubuntu OS'(14.06, 22.04.6, and 20.4 specifically), It just leads me to this endless terminal thing. is there a way to fix this?
[Error Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEoOc.jpg)